# How to write a signal handler to catch SIGSEGV?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, signal-handling, mprotect

I want to write a signal handler to catch SIGSEGV. 
I protect a block of memory for read or write using

```
char *buffer;
char *p;
char a;
int pagesize = 4096;

mprotect(buffer,pagesize,PROT_NONE)
```

This protects pagesize bytes of memory starting at buffer against any reads or writes.

Second, I try to read the memory:

```
p = buffer;
a = *p
```

This will generate a SIGSEGV, and my handler will be called. 
So far so good. My problem is that, once the handler is called, I want to change the access write of the memory by doing

```
mprotect(buffer,pagesize,PROT_READ);
```

and continue normal functioning of my code. I do not want to exit the function.
On future writes to the same memory, I want to catch the signal again and modify the write rights and then record that event.

Here is [the code](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

char *buffer;
int flag=0;

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *unused)
{
    printf("Got SIGSEGV at address: 0x%lx\n",(long) si->si_addr);
    printf("Implements the handler only\n");
    flag=1;
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *p; char a;
    int pagesize;
    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        handle_error("sigaction");

    pagesize=4096;

    /* Allocate a buffer aligned on a page boundary;
       initial protection is PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE */

    buffer = memalign(pagesize, 4 * pagesize);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        handle_error("memalign");

    printf("Start of region:        0x%lx\n", (long) buffer);
    printf("Start of region:        0x%lx\n", (long) buffer+pagesize);
    printf("Start of region:        0x%lx\n", (long) buffer+2*pagesize);
    printf("Start of region:        0x%lx\n", (long) buffer+3*pagesize);
    //if (mprotect(buffer + pagesize * 0, pagesize,PROT_NONE) == -1)
    if (mprotect(buffer + pagesize * 0, pagesize,PROT_NONE) == -1)
        handle_error("mprotect");

    //for (p = buffer ; ; )
    if(flag==0)
    {
        p = buffer+pagesize/2;
        printf("It comes here before reading memory\n");
        a = *p; //trying to read the memory
        printf("It comes here after reading memory\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (mprotect(buffer + pagesize * 0, pagesize,PROT_READ) == -1)
        handle_error("mprotect");
        a = *p;
        printf("Now i can read the memory\n");

    }
/*  for (p = buffer;p<=buffer+4*pagesize ;p++ ) 
    {
        //a = *(p);
        *(p) = 'a';
        printf("Writing at address %p\n",p);

    }*/

    printf("Loop completed\n");     /* Should never happen */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The problem is that only the signal handler runs and I can't return to the main function after catching the signal.

Comment: thanks nos for editing..I appreciate that. I need to spend some time to learn editing my questions..

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.
(for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )  The compiler will tell you: 1) parameter `argc` unused 2) parameter `argv` unused (suggest using main() signature of: `int main( void )`  3) local variable `p` used in the `else` code block without being initialized.  4) parameter `unused` unused, suggest: add statement: `(void)unused;` as first line in that function. 5) local variable `a` set but not used.

Comment: NEVER use `printf()` in a signal handler! The function `write()` would be ok to use, but best to not do any I/O in a signal handler, just set a flag and let the main line of code be checking that flag

Comment: the variable `pagesize` is declared as an `int`, but it should be declared as a `size_t`

Comment: the `sig` parameter should be compared to SIGSEGV, as there are other signals, and such a comparison would removed the compiler message about a unused `sig` parameter

Comment: the function: `memalign()` is obsolete.  the code should be using: `posix_memalign()`  which also requires the definition of `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` with a value greater/equal to 200112L

Comment: the code (probably) should use: `getpagesize()` rather than hardcoding the value `4096`.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

When your signal handler returns (assuming it doesn't call exit or longjmp or something that prevents it from actually returning), the code will continue at the point the signal occurred, reexecuting the same instruction.  Since at this point, the memory protection has not been changed, it will just throw the signal again, and you'll be back in your signal handler in an infinite loop.

So to make it work, you have to call mprotect in the signal handler.  Unfortunately, as Steven Schansker notes, mprotect is not async-safe, so you can't safely call it from the signal handler.  So, as far as POSIX is concerned, you're screwed.

Fortunately on most implementations (all modern UNIX and Linux variants as far as I know), mprotect is a system call, so is [safe to call from within a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675040/does-linux-allow-any-system-call-to-be-made-from-signal-handlers), so you can do most of what you want.  The problem is that if you want to change the protections back after the read, you'll have to do that in the main program after the read.

Another possibility is to do something with the third argument to the signal handler, which points at an OS and arch specific structure that contains info about where the signal occurred.  On Linux, this is a *ucontext* structure, which contains machine-specific info about the $PC address and other register contents where the signal occurred.  If you modify this, you change where the signal handler will return to, so you can change the $PC to be just after the faulting instruction so it won't re-execute after the handler returns.  This is very tricky to get right (and non-portable too).

**edit**

The `ucontext` structure is defined in `<ucontext.h>`.  Within the `ucontext` the field `uc_mcontext` contains the machine context, and within *that*, the array `gregs` contains the general register context.  So in your signal handler:

```
ucontext *u = (ucontext *)unused;
unsigned char *pc = (unsigned char *)u->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP];
```

will give you the pc where the exception occurred.  You can read it to figure out what instruction it
was that faulted, and do something different.

As far as the portability of calling mprotect in the signal handler is concerned, any system that follows either the SVID spec or the BSD4 spec should be safe -- they allow calling any system call (anything in section 2 of the manual) in a signal handler.

Comment: Right, you can perform the memory access on behalf of the program (like a VM) and then update the instruction pointer.  Calling `mprotect` is definitely easier.

Comment: hi chris, 
You have given me some useful information. Thanks for that.. Can you tell me how can i read the info in the ucontext structure (3rd argument and change the $PC) . I am curious to know about it.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt, I did not understand clearly what are u saying, request you to be slightly more elaborate.

Comment: @chris, looks like i can do mprotect inside the signal handler and then return back safely to do my normal execution. I am not sure about portability as you guys mentioned , but I hope it is fine in my case.
Thanks all for the help..

Comment: @chris thanks for the explanation, i will see the PC using ur technique .

Comment: `mprotect` is not formally async-signal-safe, but in reality, there is no good reason an implementation of `mprotect` would fail to be AS-safe, since it has to be implemented as a syscall.

Comment: One can also use SIGTRAP to detect the start of the next instruction.

Comment: @col6y: that requires replacing the next instruction with a breakpoint instruction, which is possible, though non-trivial (finding the next instruction on x86 is tricky).  I'm not aware of any UNIX variant that will allow single-stepping via a signal handler, though most allow it via another process and ptrace(2)

Comment: @ChrisDodd If I'm not mistaken, you can also set the trap flag, which will cause SIGTRAP on every instruction.

Comment: @col6y: that sounds plausible, though I've never seen anything like that done.  The OS might interfere with setting the flag.  Even if it didn't, you might trap the same instruction again -- need to check the CPU manual to understand precisely how the trap flag works on your processor.

Comment: @ChrisDodd take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27080741/3369324) - that's where I found out about it.

Comment: "mprotect is a system call, so is safe to call from within a signal handler": if you have any docs to support that, please add the quote at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675040/does-linux-allow-any-system-call-to-be-made-from-signal-handlers

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 29):

You've fallen into the trap that all people do when they first try to handle signals.  The trap?  Thinking that you can actually do anything **useful** with signal handlers.  From a signal handler, you are only allowed to call asynchronous and reentrant-safe library calls.

See [this CERT advisory](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers) as to why and a list of the POSIX functions that are safe.

Note that printf(), which you are already calling, is not on that list.

Nor is mprotect.  You're not allowed to call it from a signal handler.  It **might** work, but I can promise you'll run into problems down the road.  Be really careful with signal handlers, they're tricky to get right!

**EDIT**

Since I'm being a portability douchebag at the moment already, I'll point out that you [also shouldn't write to shared (i.e. global) variables](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SIG31-C.+Do+not+access+shared+objects+in+signal+handlers) without taking the proper precautions.

Comment: Hi steven , 
If I can't do anything useful inside the signal handler, I will be OK if I can update some counters inside it and return back to main and normally run my code, is it possible ?

Comment: quoting from the CERT advisory, "they may call other functions provided that all implementations to which the code is ported guarantee that these functions are asynchronous—safe".  On linux that includes a lot more functions.

Comment: Sure, but you have to just be aware of the problem!  I can't name off the top of my head which functions are and aren't signal safe, and I doubt many could!

Comment: The CERT Secure Coding is a great site, I didn't know about it. It seems I got some new reading for a while :)

Comment: If you can't do anything useful in signal handlers, why do they exist?

Comment: Best is to put the sighandler data into a reentrant queue and then process it from the main process loop.

Comment: "You're not allowed to call [mprotect] from a signal handler." Only if you need to strictly conform to POSIX. Glibc's mprotect today is async-signal-safe: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory-Protection.html#index-mprotect

Comment: this answer is mostly incorrect in practice. You can do lots of useful things inside a signal handler, they're just not guaranteed to succeed. The good news is you're going to crash anyway, so do whatever you want. I'm currently printing out stacktraces from them with embedded source code and its worked 100% of the time (so far). If it doesn't work, I'm on worse off than I was before.

Answer (score 13):

You can recover from SIGSEGV on linux.  Also you can recover from segmentation faults on Windows (you'll see a structured exception instead of a signal).  But [the POSIX standard doesn't guarantee recovery](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG35-C.+Do+not+return+from+SIGSEGV,+SIGILL,+or+SIGFPE+signal+handlers), so your code will be very non-portable.

Take a look at [libsigsegv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/).

Answer (score 5):

You should not return from the signal handler, as then behavior is undefined. Rather, jump out of it with longjmp.

This is only okay if the signal is generated in an async-signal-safe function. Otherwise, behavior is undefined if the program ever calls another async-signal-unsafe function. Hence, the signal handler should only be established immediately before it is necessary, and disestablished as soon as possible.

In fact, I know of very few uses of a SIGSEGV handler:

- use an async-signal-safe backtrace library to log a backtrace, then die.
- in a VM such as the JVM or CLR: check if the SIGSEGV occurred in JIT-compiled code.  If not, die; if so, then throw a language-specific exception (*not* a C++ exception), which works because the JIT compiler knew that the trap could happen and generated appropriate frame unwind data.
- clone() and exec() a debugger (do *not* use fork() – that calls callbacks registered by pthread_atfork()).

Finally, note that any action that triggers SIGSEGV is probably UB, as this is accessing invalid memory. However, this would not be the case if the signal was, say, SIGFPE.

Comment: mmap() & mprotect() are often used in combination with a SIGSEGV handler to trap memory accesses to certain regions, and the behavior is defined in this case as the memory access is not invalid, but protected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a compilation problem using `ucontext_t` or struct `ucontext` (present in `/usr/include/sys/ucontext.h`)

http://www.mail-archive.com/arch-general@archlinux.org/msg13853.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, the talk about how only a subset of functions can be called from signal handlers is a generalization. It's correct in case you don't know where exactly the invalid memory access will happen - then it can happen in a place where it's not safe to call them (like, already inside one of them). However, if you're writing some sort of a "probing" code and you know which instruction can fail, in your own code, then I see no problem with calling those "prohibited" functions because you know you were not in a bad place.