# Trying to single step through program with trap-flag and trap-signal-handler, crash on vsyscall

Tags: c, linux, signals, system-calls

I'd like to create a complete instruction trace of the execution of a program, to collect some stats etc. I first tried using linux' ptrace functionality to step through a program (using the tutorial [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/23/how-debuggers-work-part-1)). This creates two processes, the traced one and the debugger, and they communicate via signals. I only got around 16K instructions per second (on 1.6GHz Atom), so this is too slow for anything non-trivial.

I thought the interprocess communication via signals is too slow, so I tried setting up the debugging in the same process as the execution: Set the trap flag, and create a signal handler. When a software interrupt is used to make a syscall, the trap flag should be saved, the kernel would use it's own flags - so I thought. But my program somehow gets killed by signal SIGTRAP.

This is what I set up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int cycle = 0;
void trapHandler(int signum) {
  if (cycle % 262144 == 0) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO," trap\n",6);
  }
  cycle += 1;
}

void startTrace() {
  // set up signal handler                                                                                                         
  signal(SIGTRAP, trapHandler);

  // set trap flag                                                                                                                 
  asm volatile("pushfl\n"
               "orl $0x100, (%esp)\n"
               "popfl\n"
               );
}

void printRock() {
  char* s = "Rock\n";
  asm(
      "movl $5, %%edx\n" // message length                                                                                         
      "movl %0, %%ecx\n" // message to write                                                                                       
      "movl $1, %%ebx\n" // file descriptor (stdout)                                                                               
      "movl $4, %%eax\n" // system call number (sys_write)                                                                         
      "int  $0x80\n"   // sycall                                                                                                   
      : // no output regs                                                                                                          
      : "r"(s) // input text                                                                                                       
      : "edx","ecx","ebx","eax"
      );
}

int main() {
  startTrace();

  // some computation                                                                                                              
  int x = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    x += i*2;
  }

  printRock();
  write(STDOUT_FILENO,"Paper\n",6);
  write(STDOUT_FILENO,"Scissors\n",9);
}
```

When running, this gives:

```
 trap
 trap
 trap
Rock
Paper
 trap
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

So now we get about 250K instructions per second, still slow but non-trivial executions are possible. But there is that core dump that appears to happen between the two write calls. In GDB, we see where it happens:

```
Dump of assembler code for function __kernel_vsyscall:
   0xb76f3414 <+0>:  push   %ecx
   0xb76f3415 <+1>:  push   %edx
   0xb76f3416 <+2>:  push   %ebp
   0xb76f3417 <+3>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
   0xb76f3419 <+5>:  sysenter 
   0xb76f341b <+7>:  nop
   0xb76f341c <+8>:  nop
   0xb76f341d <+9>:  nop
   0xb76f341e <+10>: nop
   0xb76f341f <+11>: nop
   0xb76f3420 <+12>: nop
   0xb76f3421 <+13>: nop
   0xb76f3422 <+14>: int    $0x80
=> 0xb76f3424 <+16>: pop    %ebp
   0xb76f3425 <+17>: pop    %edx
   0xb76f3426 <+18>: pop    %ecx
   0xb76f3427 <+19>: ret
```

And the backtrace:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
#0  0xb77c5424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb76d0553 in __write_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#2  0x0804847d in trapHandler (signum=5) at count.c:8
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0xb77c5424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#5  0xb76d0553 in __write_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#6  0x08048537 in main () at count.c:49
```

It appears syscalls that happen via `int 80` are fine, but the write calls use the kernel's VIDSO/vsyscall break somehow (I didn't know about this functionality, closer described [here](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html)). It may be related to using `sysenter` rather than `int 80`, maybe the trap flag survives when stepping into the kernel. I don't quite get what's going with the recursive `__kernel_vsyscall` calls. I also don't get why there's an `int 80` call inside the `__kernel_vsyscall` function.

Does anybody have a suggestion what's going on, and how to fix this? Maybe it's possible to disable the VDSO/vsysicall? Or is it possible to override the `__kernel_vsyscall` function with one that uses `int 80` rather than `sysenter`?

Answer (score 2):

Answering own question.
I didn't figure out what was happening or explain it in detail, but I found a workaround: disable VDSO. That can be done via

```
sudo sysctl vm.vdso_enabled=0
```

With this, this whole single stepping through a program works, including stepping across system calls. Disclaimer: don't blame me if things go bad.

EDIT: After updating my Linux (32-bit x86) much later, this error doesn't occur anymore. Maybe it was a bug that was fixed.