# Assembly exception handling

Tags: assembly, exception, x86, elf, disassembly

I created a assembly referencing invalid address.

```
.global main
main:
 push %eax
 call 0x12341234 # invalid address
```

I compiled and run it on **linux**, and the result was `segmentation fault` of course.

However I want to do something like `call my_exception_handler`
whenever it referencing **invalid address**, instead of raising `segmentation fault`.

Is there any method to do this in assembly level?

Comment: That depends on which operating you are programming for.  Some operating systems provide methods to recover from such exceptions.

Comment: @fuz Oh I missed mentioning that. I use Linux. Ubuntu 16.04 x86 in detail.

Comment: It won't be a C++-style exception.

What you can do is install a *signal handler* for `SIGSEGV`.  [How to write a signal handler to catch SIGSEGV?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663592).  Doing this from asm may give you more control than from compiled C, because most C library functions aren't safe from signal handlers.  But direct system calls mostly are, I think.

Comment: @Jiwon In this case you can install a signal handler for `SIGSEGV` and `SIGBUS` , determine if the cause of the segmentation violation was a stray function call, and then jump to your exception handler.  You can also just handle the exception inside your signal handler.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate.  In asm for Linux specifically, you don't have to worry about nearly as much C / POSIX undefined behaviour.  The details of how you'd go about writing a handler may differ, since I *think* you can use `sys_write` safely from a SIGSEGV handler, while you can't use C stdio functions like printf.  If anyone thinks we should reopen, let me know (or vote to reopen yourself).  But there might be a more specific duplicate; I didn't look for long.