# Is there a way to return the address which caused SIGSEGV in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am a C dummy and working on a C project which asked me to write a signal handler to catch SIGSEGV signal and perform some operations.

Basically, the main program will try to access a memory chunk that is neither readable or writable. When the main program access this chunk of memory it will raise a SIGSEGV signal, and in my signal handler function I will catch the signal and use mprotect() to convert that memory chunk into readable & writable.

But I don't know is there any way to get the address which caused SIGSEGV when signal is catched by my signal handler. I cannot do anything if I don't have the actual address which caused SIGSEGV. And I am not allowed to grab address from main into my signal handler.

can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: doesnt sound like a 'C Dummy' project at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663456/how-to-write-a-signal-handler-to-catch-sigsegv

Comment: the siginfo_t passed to the handler has a ton of info in it http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html

Comment: If your SIGSEGV handler returns, you enter the world of undefined behavior...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least on Linux the answer is yes.

You use [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to register your signal handler, and you set the `SA_SIGINFO` flag and set a `sa_sigaction` handler.

This gives you access to a `siginfo_t` (second argument to your signal handler), which (among other things) contains a `void *si_addr;` field that (for `SIGSEGV`) contains the faulting address.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#include <signal.h>

void my_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext) {
    ... info->si_addr ...
}

...
struct sigaction act = {0};
act.sa_sigaction = my_handler;
act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL);
```

See `man 2 sigaction` for details.

Comment: Hello, I cannot find si_addr in my *info structure, there are only _sifields, si_code, si_errno, and si_signo.

Comment: Hello, I found the si_addr under _sifields->_sigfault->si_addr.

Comment: Hello, now I am in another trouble: when I try to compile my handler prototype says "unknown type name ‘siginfo_t’". Also, when I try to assign my handler function like this: 
     "act.__sigaction_handler.sa_sigaction = handler_function;" I got the error:  "‘union <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘__sigaction_handler’"  Is there anyway to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @ZiruiBai 1) What OS are you on? 2) What happens when you try my code?

Comment: 1. ubuntu 16.04.               2. your code won't work on my machine, I have to use act.__sigaction_handler.sa_sigaction to assign handler function and use info->_sifields._sigfault.si_addr to get fault address.

Comment: won't compile, showing error "unknown type name ‘siginfo_t’"

Comment: I changed my code as the same with yours now, and this is the only error when compile.

Comment: @ZiruiBai Can you post your source file and compilation options somewhere?

Comment: Hello: I kind of found the reason. when I put prototype within .c file associated with my code it will compile, but when I put this into .h file associated with my code it won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184439/discussion-between-melpomene-and-zirui-bai).